# How to set a value to a material ui select field?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, select, material-ui

I am using material UI Select for year field. I would like to set a default year based on the value in the state. I am populating years based on a year array.

Following is the method which is used to create the year array I call this method in component did mount:-

```
updateYear = () => {
    var start = 1950;
    var end = new Date().getFullYear() - 20;
    var yearValue = [];
    for (var year = start; year <= end; year++) {
        yearValue.push({ key: year, text: year, value: year });
    }
    console.log("yearValue", yearValue);
    this.setState({ yearValue: yearValue });
};
```

This is the code for my material UI select:-

```
<Select
    value={this.state.year}
    onChange={this.handleChange_year}
    inputProps={{
        name: "year",
        id: "year"
    }}
>
{this.state.yearValue &&
    this.state.yearValue.map(year => {
    return <MenuItem value={year.value}>{year.value}</MenuItem>;
})}
</Select>
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: which material UI are you using?

Comment: Hi, Mayank I am using Material UI for react.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this:

To set default value, in component did mount you can add:
`this.setState({ year: yearValue[0].value })`

then, edit the handleChange_year method:

```
handleChange_year = (event) => {
    this.setState({ year: event.target.value })
}
```